# Why does this javascript throw this particular error?

Tags: javascript, html

In my HTML code I have a button that when pressed runs a javascript function.  This is the HTML code for the button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="repeatName()">Click me!</button>
```

I want the user to enter something into a text field (which is inside of a form).  This is the code for the text field:

```
<input type="text" name="txtName" />
```

I want this div's innerHTML to be changed according to the information put in the name textbox once the button is pressed.  This is the code for the div:

```
<div name="editThis" width="50px" height="50px" border="1px">

</div>
```

When the button is clicked, I want it to run the function below.  It is supposed to change the innerHTML of the div.

```
function repeatName() {
    var editField = document.getElementsByName("editThis").innerHTML;
    var repeatedName = document.theForm.txtName.value;

    editField = (repeatedName + " is the value.")

}
```

THE PROBLEM IS that whenever the button is clicked, I see this error in the Firefox error console:

```
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Cannot modify properties of a WrappedNative"  nsresult: "0x80570034 (NS_ERROR_XPC_CANT_MODIFY_PROP_ON_WN)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://global/content/bindings/autocomplete.xml :: onxblpopuphiding :: line 825"  data: no]
```

What is this error and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName), `document.getElementsByName(str)` returns "a list of elements".

It's clear that "a list of elements" doesn't have a singular `.innerHTML` property. I'd guess that the specific error relates to your browser's internal mechanism for representing that list in its own `WrappedNative` type.

Iterate the results instead; in your case, you only need the first result, so get it with the array accessor syntax `[0]`.

*But*, since `name` properties relate to form components, you should use `id` instead. Retrieving an element by ID is easier, since IDs are [supposed to be] unique.

Also, since Javascript has no references, you cannot store `innerHTML` in a variable and change it expecting the original property to change; you must make the assignment in the same statement in which you notate `innerHTML`:

```
function repeatName() {
    var editField = document.getElementsById("editField");
    var repeatedName = document.theForm.txtName.value;

    editField.innerHTML = repeatedName + " is the value."
}
```

Comment: Also, this will only change the value of the variable `editField`, but it won't change the `innerHTML` of `editThis`.

Comment: What is supposed to happen when you/he sets the value of editField...that isn't going to change the innerHTML of the element.

Comment: Need to say `editField = document.getElementsByName("editThis")[0]` and then `editField.innerHTML = ...` rather than `editField = ...`

Comment: It is much better to reference standards than community wikis.

Comment: @RobG: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM is about as good as it gets in terms of practical, legible and reliable documentation. If you can suggest an alternative, go for it.

Comment: Tomalak - while the Mozilla documentation is useful, it is a community wiki where anyone can create and account and edit or add pages. Also, Gecko implements many non-standard features, those unfamiliar with the documentation may not know to look at the specification section of articles to determine standards compliance.

Comment: @RobG: The community wiki page contains links to two standards references on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

I think Tomalak has it right. Alternately, you can give your div an id, and then use getElementById, which will return a single object and not a collection.

i.e.

```
<div id="editThis" .... > .... </div>
...
...
document.getElementById("editThis").innerHTML = repeatedName + " is the value";
```

Answer (score 0):

Div elements don't have a name attribute, so use an id instead.

```
<div id="editThis" ...>
```

Then use:

```
function repeatName() {
  var editField = document.getElementById("editThis");
  if (editField) {
    editField.innerHTML = document.theForm.txtName.value + ' is the value';
  }
}
```